# Why doesn't animation work in chrome?

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, firefox

Following code implements a marquee like animation that is working just on firefox. It is not working in chrome. What could be the reason for this ? Here is the [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vn2Vu/) that will show up only in the firefox.

*CSS :*

```
/* define the animation */
@-webkit-keyframes marquee {
  0%   { transform: translate(0, 0); }
  100% { transform: translate(-100%, 0); }
} 

@-moz-keyframes marquee {
  0% { transform: translate(0, 0); }
  100% { transform: translate(-100%, 0); }
}

/* define your limiting container */
.marquee {
  border: solid 2px;
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
/* this is the tray moving around your container */
.marquee span {
  display: inline-block;
  padding-left: 100%;
  text-indent: 0;
  animation: marquee 15s linear infinite; /* here you select the animation */
}
/* pause the animation on mouse over */
.marquee span:hover {
  animation-play-state: paused
}
```

*HTML :*

```
<p class="marquee">
    <span>
    Hey ! What's up?
    </span>
</p>
```

Debugging in chrome highlights this :

[image]

Comment: did you try -webkit-animation-play-state property and other -webkit prefixes for animations?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Haven't got Chrome installed currently, but remember to prefix `-webkit` to all CSS3 functions for compatibility.

```
@-webkit-keyframes marquee {
  0%   { -webkit-transform: translate(0, 0); }
  100% { -webkit-transform: translate(-100%, 0); }
}
```

EDIT: For the error you added, utilise the above.

```
/* this is the tray moving around your container */
.marquee span {
  display: inline-block;
  padding-left: 100%;
  text-indent: 0;
  animation: marquee 15s linear infinite; /* here you select the animation */
  -webkit-animation: marquee 15s linear infinite; /* here you select the animation */
}
/* pause the animation on mouse over */
.marquee span:hover {
  animation-play-state: paused;
  -webkit-animation-play-state: paused;
}
```

Comment: How can I make the animation move up like its moving left-to-right now ?

Answer (score 0):

Try adding the -webkit- prefix to make it work in webkit browsers. [Reference](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_animations.asp)

```
/* this is the tray moving around your container */
.marquee span {
  display: inline-block;
  padding-left: 100%;
  text-indent: 0;
  -webkit-animation: marquee 15s linear infinite; /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
  animation: marquee 15s linear infinite; /* here you select the animation */
}

/* pause the animation on mouse over */
.marquee span:hover {
  -webkit-animation-play-state: paused /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
  animation-play-state: paused
}
```

As pointed out by James Hunt, you might need to prefix the "transform" attribute with -webkit- aswell.

Answer (score 0):

in the "marque span" css definition, add the -webkit- prefix to the animation attribute do it will work in chrome and safari